# How to build a legend with color gradient geomap using Echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

In Apache Echarts is it possible render e geomap with a legend like in the picture above?
something like: colored-square + value (-2.4) + label (PIEMONTE)
Unfortunately it seems that the default render has only the gradient bar:
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=geo-beef-cuts

[image: italy image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very hacky solution utilizing the fact that pie charts have special rights in [legend](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#legend.data.name):

> If it is a pie chart, legend name can also be the name of a single data item.

So I just added a pie chart with the appropriate legend and made it invisable by setting its width and height to 0.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-usa&code=LYTwwgFghgTgLgOgM4QPYHcAyqoBMCWAdgOYAUAlANwBQ1AxqoUnAAS5RxQsC8LA2tRYsA3i0JRgAUwBcLAOQBBADZQARhKhyANCwBuUJQFcZLACwAOAEyWADJYDMLAL5bBIsRJOKVSANaadfSMTAHZ7AEZTUwBOZ1chUXEpWUUYfAAvRgC9A2NZADYAVkL7S2K4t0TPFIUYfyYoJG0c4NlLaJjwiIqEj2T5MAN8ADNUGEJ8bKC8lntzG1NI-xse9ySvMFQlMbxUZumTQvDzEMKrVar-uU3CQkk6OHw6Qzh93JN7Quibe1MQi76XgAIpIVOhYJI3q0WNFwiEbNFLAD1ikgfhmGkHixUMMWJsjMBVJMoTN8qVycjqvIAGLbNLsEkmcLRCKnfLmSlXADikjGxGJgXesmisJFpkKnK8AAkoOD8PhGbIuoiIo4XJVASkAJLsNCKljhL6FEKWDnq3oo-RapRKIiodH68Km05lCXmtZUuRawgEKDifVFexhX6S7UYKZC2Y2EKLcz5UPyADSfqQjX1pvMXxsbviHquickhDghjovhA-tMcwWhoTcmwhnRk39guhpnyNmOLNrAFkoERIS2Zl12syke7Ll5ezAQCoffqzuZxWSe41U3QIIYkJI4HAmoOTPl8m3IqYe08IPhiH79dFzOZ7PZ22fbpIkKhOPOg7D7LFx5r5N26JIEB-AAA6gQq-5tLeMSWPGf6WnIgFIG-hhpAGdjMnePaMJwzYtEONjZpE4S1gAcpIqgwI0_iOpmxRlORkj6AyUEsJYpzmCypEIZ6FHoCwMrAKBKD4DAA4EUypTRscTECQAUpIMBbuWbF3keWZySw3aSAAHk8exsbY9FzFpACaYy-I60TGnY-Q8bmE4pGRYxwBAeKwFsRARtC0QutGaqOf-cgufA7lAlAvjvj5pIivkpq1gA8hehmSUqhpRNYOYaohiW-CoaDADFHzmJEVgrLxVyJeJxCMPqcwip8gU5Z6AAKhZMDO-gTMVSocWSJTwUFiEAEpoLgkgsFqSCzrgjrZnYiK1gAyqgLzuYMMBefhByyH8Dgms1Fqeqt60sBFUUfmpD6fKelVeAAKh1r5bhJu0sBp8WVrWT26WmRntl8thHXmXgAKqcBA6b0c6tYAGpKcAuEBnBHYOS1Vxw2J_I9fqpWZnG_z3SkADqjQXiQcB1Wx7J-R2Y7DZ6JOvqwWMwDjAppQa9GLCDTnyCT6IMEwRDziaZK3rWJMgKgwBEMQYtHk6tatcY8CoCwI0GfVh7wouzjUAAujQ1AACQIMQ26kCNiWJQ9AD6rUKA9UosAA1PIAD07CcJ7q7bp7luoJ7YPLQoCAAFZvoQzTDIYhAPPgjAsKQm5QPJ0fkCIbigJAsCIBeE3YHg8sUDQQj3NA8BIAgNXonASm9qBpByKHCjNGnGeMDowhuEIyg0VAsi90Io8sEokjDHAsgALRdOEuZj1ToFtIUi-j-g-C4G5SqFH3qxCDKcr4MP-9CBPU-z-E4Q2OvQjL205h3ywm_bxAsh72P7pCHIqtKVTmttanzHufSe08WAzxCPkZ-D92LQLPi_LeO92L7ycG4JwVA3CoFAo8ZOvAR6j0eHACewCQEN10uA1uYcWCtWwYYFQuDCAsAAKLMHwEVBuSAU62CdOQbQCCkCGFUOQyhEVOAsGGFtYAL90DoAQHQQsgia61V0PwkBLBBGqFtIQXwKQIA7hXp7T2si5EKKYJuC2qBdCe1Atglm3sOBQAcZwLcu4ED6OAEoNRICL6ULSMQfRchUHryplsR4K9s7qLgP4y2MAUj4AbsAbxY8UAYBBCoEAshb4IOiSmBJSdCBAjQhwApWSECWGCfvXQ6JDAGCbqQseaBdBKUwEQXREiDBbmfr4j-2SonYLaH0kBYx8CFkoWgNImQiwGGSaPOWhBelESIs_IqulZBViWcshBRARp-ktg0kBDA6SyAEOosecgADEqp8g2Vmeoy54pTiqFMHckBlyYx4FwOEV55yLlqFwNESQ0Qfmj0uZIGwwx7DDHMCCn-FzhgIuGKoYYsL5DwskOC74qLLnDHYJIey2L4VtlwJWQluAwh2BCISqAhQiJwSCWclghsEHfwPuPSQlsfQHPviAUCXgkB0C2jaV5PSWC0pgQMsVQyx4jLGSkZp8AngzOfluCeDxJC4G7KgCashhidMkM_CAkhLz6LaPCZ-Psh5sEcQgIqzc44J0YSnBJkhgBZwIeo8SxZxjuHei64ACADg6EtP6hA6wdAGQWfIJAABHWp4k5DOHLiAjBz9RgwA4Q3OJgIeAAD5rWcAQMMIguBSD-rzSwUN6weDcF4Oscggb3juxYAAIlbc28NlSUlKVGUgE5CCPVkN5V4CCA4EFCEtbIS1z9z5qFBMPVJ6BdX6tZY041ATwHSpAa_ZBW6x7pCyc_VdkSzmITbjQ7BrDHgcNfCCuAw6Uh2pBVtCQshonGBnSwO1KQ24gtdaBaAwE-0nsZSoVQ86QOMo0WgJdLB32SHHaPNBjLj0TscVOxxLL97MqEE4ZNucq6IFcYlHBBTSDYMYZgjBlAgA):

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Alabama', value: 4822023 },
  { name: 'Alaska', value: 731449 },
  { name: 'Arizona', value: 6553255 },
  { name: 'Arkansas', value: 2949131 },
  { name: 'California', value: 38041430 },
  { name: 'Colorado', value: 5187582 },
  { name: 'Connecticut', value: 3590347 },
  { name: 'Delaware', value: 917092 },
  { name: 'District of Columbia', value: 632323 },
  { name: 'Florida', value: 19317568 },
  { name: 'Georgia', value: 9919945 },
  { name: 'Hawaii', value: 1392313 },
  { name: 'Idaho', value: 1595728 },
  { name: 'Illinois', value: 12875255 },
  { name: 'Indiana', value: 6537334 },
  { name: 'Iowa', value: 3074186 },
  { name: 'Kansas', value: 2885905 },
  { name: 'Kentucky', value: 4380415 },
  { name: 'Louisiana', value: 4601893 },
  { name: 'Maine', value: 1329192 },
  { name: 'Maryland', value: 5884563 },
  { name: 'Massachusetts', value: 6646144 },
  { name: 'Michigan', value: 9883360 },
  { name: 'Minnesota', value: 5379139 },
  { name: 'Mississippi', value: 2984926 },
  { name: 'Missouri', value: 6021988 },
  { name: 'Montana', value: 1005141 },
  { name: 'Nebraska', value: 1855525 },
  { name: 'Nevada', value: 2758931 },
  { name: 'New Hampshire', value: 1320718 },
  { name: 'New Jersey', value: 8864590 },
  { name: 'New Mexico', value: 2085538 },
  { name: 'New York', value: 19570261 },
  { name: 'North Carolina', value: 9752073 },
  { name: 'North Dakota', value: 699628 },
  { name: 'Ohio', value: 11544225 },
  { name: 'Oklahoma', value: 3814820 },
  { name: 'Oregon', value: 3899353 },
  { name: 'Pennsylvania', value: 12763536 },
  { name: 'Rhode Island', value: 1050292 },
  { name: 'South Carolina', value: 4723723 },
  { name: 'South Dakota', value: 833354 },
  { name: 'Tennessee', value: 6456243 },
  { name: 'Texas', value: 26059203 },
  { name: 'Utah', value: 2855287 },
  { name: 'Vermont', value: 626011 },
  { name: 'Virginia', value: 8185867 },
  { name: 'Washington', value: 6897012 },
  { name: 'West Virginia', value: 1855413 },
  { name: 'Wisconsin', value: 5726398 },
  { name: 'Wyoming', value: 576412 },
  { name: 'Puerto Rico', value: 3667084 }
];

$.get(ROOT_PATH + '/data/asset/geo/USA.json', function (usaJson) {
  myChart.hideLoading();
  echarts.registerMap('USA', usaJson, {
    Alaska: {
      left: -131,
      top: 25,
      width: 15
    },
    Hawaii: {
      left: -110,
      top: 28,
      width: 5
    },
    'Puerto Rico': {
      left: -76,
      top: 26,
      width: 2
    }
  });
  option = {
    title: {
      text: 'USA Population Estimates (2012)',
      subtext: 'Data from www.census.gov',
      sublink: 'http://www.census.gov/popest/data/datasets.html',
      left: 'right'
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'item',
      showDelay: 0,
      transitionDuration: 0.2
    },
    visualMap: {
      hoverLink: false,
      left: 50,
      top: 20,
      orient: 'horizontal',
      min: 500000,
      max: 38000000,
      inRange: {
        color: [
          '#313695',
          '#4575b4',
          '#74add1',
          '#abd9e9',
          '#e0f3f8',
          '#ffffbf',
          '#fee090',
          '#fdae61',
          '#f46d43',
          '#d73027',
          '#a50026'
        ]
      },
    },
    legend: {
      type: 'scroll',
      left: 50,
      top: 50,
      orient: 'vertical',
      selectedMode: false,
      height: 270,
      data: data.map(function (item) {
        return { value: item.value, name: item.name, icon: 'square' };
      }),
      formatter: name => data.find(item => item.name === name).value + " " + name,
    },
    series: [
      {
        type: 'pie',
        data: data,
        label: {show: false},
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
        z: 0,
      },
      {
        name: 'USA PopEstimates',
        type: 'map',
        roam: true,
        map: 'USA',
        emphasis: {
          label: {
            show: true
          }
        },
        data: data
      }
    ]
  };
  myChart.setOption(option);
});
```